# How to clean ios app tmp folder

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that can take pictures (saving them with "Allow External Storage File" flag) and noticed that its size was growing too much. After poking around I discovered that iOS created a .LINKS folder inside the tmp directory and that every time I save a picture, it gets copied both to the Documents folder and the .LINKS folder.

When the picture is deleted, its copy inside .LINKS remains there, taking space. So

1. How do I clear the tmp folder?
2. Why is this .LINKS folder being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out, you don't need to delete the contents of the tmp directory. iOS will clean this up periodically (especially when space gets low). I found this article helpful: http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/08/ios-application-directory-structure.html

The .LINKS folder is used by NSImage and related classes to cache images. I have an app that does a lot of image generation and that directory grows by 8MB each launch. But after downloading some movies to take up space, I saw the folders contents get cleared automatically.

Comment: Thanks , the answer which I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution to 1.:

```
NSArray* temp = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:NULL];
for (NSString *file in temp) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file] error:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to 1 with Swift 5

```
func deleteTemporaryFiles() {
    if let temp = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()) {
        for file in temp {
            let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(file)
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)
            } catch {
                print("Error : \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's easier to use `FileManager contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)` since it gives you an array of `URL`. No need to build a URL for each file.